# Accessing different Masterpages from Base Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have an application that uses 2 master pages. One for main pages and one for Popup pages. These both inherit from Masterpages

```
public partial class MainMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    UserBO objUser = null;

    public UserBO GetCurrentUser()
    {
        UserBO userBO = new UserBO();
     .....
     .....  
        return userBO;
    }
 }


public partial class PopupMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    UserBO objUser = null;

    public UserBO GetCurrentUser()
    {
        UserBO userBO = new UserBO();
     .....
     .....  
        return userBO;
    }
 }
```

So far so good. So my content pages all Inherit from a base class. The base class has a method that
calls the GetCurrentUser from the Base class.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
//..... 
    protected UserBO GetCurrentUserFromMasterPage()
    {
        this.Master
        Elsa.MasterPages.MainMasterPage master = (Elsa.MasterPages.MainMasterPage )this.Master;
        return master.GetCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

So here you can see that the base page casts the `MasterPage` and then calls `GetCurrentUser`.

Just for background... The masterpages get current user logged into the system and then draws itself using the info. If the user is in the session it gets it otherwise it loads from the database. I dont want the content pages to do the same so I wanted the base page to always get the current user for the content page from the master.

However my problem is, that because there is 2 master pages and all web pages are derived from Base
page.. I need to be able to cast to the correct master.

```
public partial class MyMainPage : Elsa.Pages.BasePage
{
    private long _userId = -1;

public partial class MyPopupPage : Elsa.Pages.BasePage
{
    private long _userId = -1;
```

If I put in the MasterType directive I can call the method in the content page for the correct Master.
But I dont want to call it from the content as its common method so I need it in the base.

So does anyone know how to handle this. I was thinking on deriving the BasePage again for a PopupBasePage and over writing the `GetCurrentUserFromMasterPage()` to cast to the popup master.
Or do I pass something into the BasePage constructor to tell it what to cast to.

I want to keep the impact to all my web pages to a minium as I have a lot of web pages.

Thanks M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert an extra MasterPage as the base class for your 2 current ones:

```
public partial class SiteMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
   ....
   // GetCurrentUser
}

public partial class MainMasterPage : SiteMasterPage
{
   ....
}

public partial class PopupMasterPage : SiteMasterPage
{
}
```

This will allow you to implement other common features and markup (include of CSS files) in one place as well.

Comment: Henk, this is actually what I am looking at, this very moment. So I would implement the GetCurrentUser in the SiteMasterPage and then handle the Page load etc in each of the derived master pages. would this be correct. This being the case.. does my base class then cast the master page to the SiteMasterPage.. thanks Mick

Comment: Yes, you cast to the Type you need.

Comment: Thanks Henk... this seems to have worked well. I just had to tidy up the code a bit and over ride some handlers etc. Rgds D

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense for you

using Reflection:

```
Master.GetType().GetMethod("GetCurrentUser").Invoke();
```

Comment: Not a bad suggestion Abhishek but I would rather not use reflection. I think it would be better to either pass the master page as a reference to the base page or derive the Base Page and overide the method for the PopupMaster. Just want to see if this is good programing practice or if someone else has something else that works better

Answer (score 0):

Do this :-

```
    public class MasterPageBase : MasterPage
    {

    public PageBase PageBase { get { return (PageBase)this.Page; } }

    }

    public class PageBase : Page
    {
      // Do your Extensions Here.. 
    }
```

All Pages there after Inherit from PageBase.